# Can I to generate log with cpu and memory using Log4j?

Tags: memory, log4j, cpu

I have a web application and I need to implement a library that generates a log with information of the "health" of the application and also the server hardware.
The generated log must contain processor usage information (cpu) and memory.
Can I do this with Log4j? If not, is there any Java library that allows me to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a library. Two options:

- [SIGAR](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home), ([*examples*](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar)).
- [JavaSysMon](https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon), ([*example*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24427264/870248)).

After this, you can use log4j for log *that* information.